# Intent hiding adview in android app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, admob

Following is my code -

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adview = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adrequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adview.loadAd(adrequest);
        String url = "https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCJjkahdjnbsadjsiaojdoAg";

        Intent intent=null;
        try 
        {
            intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
        {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }   
}
```

When I remove all intent part and keep only adview lines I am able to see admob banner advertisement.
But When I add the intent and start activity I do not see any ad and in logcat it shows

```
12-26 23:53:34.399: I/Ads(536): Scheduling ad refresh 30000 milliseconds from now.
12-26 23:53:34.409: I/Ads(536): Ad finished loading.
12-26 23:54:04.410: I/Ads(536): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
```

I want to place intent after adview OR adview over intent.

How can I achieve this ???

Do I have to change or add any view for intent ?? how ??

Comment: `startActivity` as the name suggests, starts a new activity. So your activity containing the adview is no longer visible.

Comment: @Henry agreed !! But how can I show banner ad and open youtube channel on same page one below another ??? Is there way to set Intent into some kind of view so it will come after adview in linearlayout ??

Answer (score 1):

In your current code,  you show an ad in your activity, then quickly start another activity (the ondevice Youtube application) which then, backgrounds your applications.

In order to play a video from YouTube while showing YOUR ad and not be backgrounded,  you will want to include and implement the android [Youtube Player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary) into your application.

Sample applications that do such a thing are here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications

Comment: Thanks @petey for quick responce. With your method I am able to see ad for split second and then it open new view and again ad becomes invisible. What I want to do is there will be small banner ad at the top and then below that youtube channel gets loaded.

Comment: Oh.  sorry I had misunderstood the question.  Please see the update.